# Move selected array index to a specified location

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reorder a selected number of array base on selected ids. For example, I have an array of:

```
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 } ]
```

And a selected id of `1,2,4`. The proper arrangement should be:

```
[ { id: 3 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }]
```

I've managed to get the arrangement to work for one selected id, but when multiple ids are selected it fails on different test cases. These all asume the same input as above.

**Input 1:** `[ 1, 2, 4 ]`, move to index `1`:

```
[ { id: 3 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 } ]
```

**Input 2:** `[ 1, 3, 4 ]`, move to index `1`:

```
[ { id: 2 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 } ]
```

**Input 3:** `[ 1, 3, 5 ]`, move to index `1`:

```
[ { id: 2 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 4 } ]
```

**Input 4:** `[ 1, 2 ]`, move to index `0` or `1`:

```
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 } ]
```

**Input 5:** `[ 4, 5 ]`, move to index `3` or `4`:

```
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 } ]
```

```js
/**
 * Function to move array
 */
function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
  if (new_index >= arr.length) {
    var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
    while (k--) {
      arr.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
};

/**
 * Function to find the index
 */
function findWithAttr(array, attr, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (array[i][attr] === value) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

/**
 * Move array to specified position
 */
function moveToSpecifiedInput(selectedImage, iMoveTo) {
  selectedImage.reverse();
  selectedImage.forEach(function(aData) {
    let old_index = findWithAttr(aImageData, 'id', aData);
    let new_index = iMoveTo - 1;

    array_move(aImageData, old_index, new_index);
  });
}
```

Comment: In your code, `aImageData` is undefined in the `moveToSpecifiedInput()`.

Comment: is 'move to index ' is inputted as well?

Comment: aImageData should be the [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}, {id:5}],  that need to be arrange.

Comment: From examples 1 & 2, I can’t tell if you’re using 0 or 1-indexing

Comment: I don't see the difference in your examples between "move to index 2" and "move to index 1". They both seem to move to index 1. And what do you mean by "move to index 0 or 1", who decides if it's 0 or 1?

Comment: @sumit yep move to index is a user specified input

Comment: You should do it in two steps: First extract the specified elements into a new array, then use `splice()` to insert that array in the specified position.

Comment: @MTCoster Im using indexing in my example but in my code im getting the value and subtract - 1 to the iMoveto in  moveToSpecifiedInput function

Comment: You should be consistent in your examples. Either 0 or 1 as the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the clarification in the comments, I think I understand your problem. This is how I’d go about solving it:

```js
function sortArray(array, sortProp, sortValues, sortIndex) {
  const elemsBySortVal = array.reduce((obj, elem, idx) => {
    obj[elem[sortProp]] = idx;
    return obj;
  }, {});
  
  let sortedKeys = sortValues.map(val => elemsBySortVal[val]);
  let sortedItems = sortedKeys.map(key => array[key]);
  let remainingItems = array.filter((_, idx) => !sortedKeys.includes(idx));
  
  return [
    ...remainingItems.slice(0, sortIndex),
    ...sortedItems,
    ...remainingItems.slice(sortIndex),
  ];
}

console.log(sortArray(
  [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 } ],
  'id',
  [ 1, 2, 4 ],
  1,
));
```

This solution works in three phases:

#### Phase 1:

This is the most complex part. Here, we take your input `array` and create a map of sort values against input indices. This is best shown by example:

**Input (`array`):**

```
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 4 } ]
```

**Output (`elemsBySortVal`):**

```
{
  1: 0,
  3: 1,
  5: 2,
  2: 3,
  4: 4,
}
```

#### Phase 2:

Now we use that map to fetch the indices in the input array of the values passed as the sort values:

**Input (`sortValues`):**

```
[ 1, 2, 4 ]
```

**Output (`sortedKeys`):**

```
[ 0, 3, 4 ]
```

This is then mapped to the elements from the input array:

**Input (`sortedKeys`):**

```
[ 0, 3, 4 ]
```

**Output (`sortedItems`):**

```
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 4 } ]
```

And finally, the remaining items are selected from the input array by using `sortedKeys` to exclude the already sorted ones:

**`remainingItems`:**

```
[ { id: 3 }, { id: 5 } ]
```

Note that all operations in phase 2 maintain the order of these arrays, even when elements are removed.

#### Phase 3:

Now we assemble the output array in 3 parts:

- Elements before the sorted section
- Elements in the sorted section
- Elements after the sorted section

The before and after parts are `slice`d from `remainingItems` using `sortIndex` as a cut point, and the sorted section is simply `sortedItems` from the previous phase.

Comment: this has problems on different selected id  like:

selected id of [1,2,3] move to index 1 the output is 4,1,2,3,5 should be 1,2,3,4,5. 
[1,2] move to index 1 output is 3,1,2,4,5 should be 1,2,3,4,5
[4,5] move to index 3 output is 1,2,3,4,5 should be 1,2,4,5,3

Comment: This solution uses 0-indexing, which is what your first example used, as well as 1 & 3 (and possibly 4 & 5). The examples you’re giving me here are using 1-indexing. Which one do you want?

Comment: The idea is if I have bunch of id  for example 6 id then the array can be move to index 0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: if I have [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 } ] then I have selected 1,3,5 then I will have  [  , { id: 2 },   , { id: 4 },     ] then I will choose which index will I append my selected id it can either be before or after id 2 and 4. I'm sorry If I'm not very clear on this.

Comment: clarified this with my lead it seems that this should be the behavior guess I was just confused with the requirements. anyway Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the elements that match the IDs from the array, and put them in a new array. Then splice that new array back into the original array.

```js
function move_array_elements(array, ids, new_index) {
  let extracted = [];
  ids.forEach(id => {
    let index = array.findIndex(el => el.id == id);
    if (index != -1) {
      extracted.push(array[index]);
      array.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  array.splice(new_index, 0, ...extracted);
  return array;
}

const orig_array = [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 } ];
console.log(move_array_elements(orig_array, [1, 2, 4], 1));
```

Comment: this almost work but with move_array_elements(orig_array, [1, 2, 4], 2);
has an output of 3,5,1,2,4  the output should be 3,1,2,4,5

Comment: Why should that be the output? My code uses zero-based indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter and splice
Please check the comments

```js
let arr=[{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}, {id:5}];
let selected=[1,2,4];
let move_2_index=1;

//filter out selected 
const selectedonly = arr.filter(a=>selected.includes(a.id));
//filter out not selected
const notselected = arr.filter(a=>!selected.includes(a.id));
//splice to insert selected on not selectd
notselected.splice(move_2_index, 0, selectedonly);
//flattern the array
final_array=notselected.flat();
console.log(final_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using `null` as a Placeholder

Details in demo.

### Demo

```js
let arr=[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}];

Array.prototype.move = function(to, moveFrom) {
  // Make a copy of the original array
  let that = [...this];
  // Declare an empty array
  let moveTo = [];
  /*
  - Compare current index with the numbers in move array (offset)
  - Replace each match with a null as a placeholder so that the
    indexes of the array is still accurate.
  - Place each match into the empty array from previous step.
  */
  that.forEach(function(obj, idx, arr) {
    if (moveFrom.indexOf(idx +1) !== -1) {
      moveTo.push(arr.splice(idx, 1, null));
    }
  });
  // Remove all nulls
  that = that.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj !== null;
  });
  /*
  Insert the new moving array into the copied array at the index
  indicated in the first parameter.
  */
  that.splice(to, 0, moveTo.flat())
  return that.flat();
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.move(1, [1, 3, 4])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.move(0, [1, 2, 5])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.move(3, [1, 2, 3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.move(1, [2, 5])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.move(2, [1, 4])));
```